# Unit test script returns exit code = 0 even if tests fail

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, exit-code

My testing script looks as follows:

```
import os
import sys
from unittest import defaultTestLoader as loader, TextTestRunner

path_to_my_project = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/../'
sys.path.insert(0, path_to_my_project)

suite = loader.discover('my_project')
runner = TextTestRunner()
runner.run(suite)
```

If I run this script, the output is:

```
$ python3 runtest.py
.....F.....
======================================================================
FAIL: test_insert (fate.test.test_operators.OperatorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chiel/Projects/tfate/libs/fate/../fate/test/test_operators.py", line 16, in test_insert
    self.assertEqual(expected, self.session.text[:14])
AssertionError: 'Foo import sys$' != 'Foo import sys'
- Foo import sys$
?               -
+ Foo import sys


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 12 tests in 0.030s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

And exit code zero:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

However, the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) states that "By default main calls `sys.exit()` with an exit code indicating success or failure of the tests run."

What is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The code is not using [`unittest.main`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main). You need to check the result using [`TestResult.wasSuccessful`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.wasSuccessful) and call [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) manually.

```
import sys

....

ret = not runner.run(suite).wasSuccessful()
sys.exit(ret)
```

Comment: Am I right to say that when a user chooses to run tests either 1) Instantiating the test class and calling the test methods from it; OR 2) using unittest.main() - the code automatically handles the call to sys.exit with appropriate code. WHEREAS, if the user were to run tests using suite and TextTestRunner, then he MUST explicitly set the sys.exit code

Comment: @variable, `unittest.main` calls `sys.exit`. 1) -> does not call sys.exit, call sys.exit() if you want to exit program   2) -> does call sys.exit, you don't need to call sys.exit() yourself.

Answer (score 25):

I had some trouble getting `TextTestRunner` results. For those like me, here is how it works:

```
"""Run all tests inside of *_test.py modules located in the same directory."""


import sys
import unittest


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('.', '*_test.py')
    test_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(resultclass=unittest.TextTestResult)
    result = test_runner.run(test_suite)
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

Comment: +1 for the Python-only implementation, which is clearly missing in python docs on test discovery [Unittest Test Discovery](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery)