# Pre-commit hook in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, pre-commit-hook

I wanted to create a pre-commit hook in IntelliJ IDEA(Community Edition) to be used to create a list of all the files selected for the commit and dump it into an xml file. I am using a Team services VCS Git repository.

I have installed the Pre-Commit plugin as well. I am not sure what code goes into the "pre-commit-hook.sh" file to be able to achieve this. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Answered [in the forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000477510-Pre-commit-hook-in-IntelliJ-IDEA).

Answer (score 1):

To change the being committed file(s) extension to `xml` in pre-commit hook, you can use the below shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# find the staged files
for Sfile in $(git diff --name-only --cached)
do
{
  mv "$Sfile" "${Sfile%.*}.xml"
  git add ${Sfile%.*}.xml
}
done
# find the unstaged files
for USfile in $(git diff --name-only)
do
{
  mv "$USfile" "${USfile%.*}.xml"
  git add ${USfile%.*}.xml
}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

As the description of the plugin is not very helpful, there is my solution for Windows to run all tests before commiting:

- create a file called pre-commit-hook.bat in the project root folder
- create a .py file, e.g. `prehook_runner.py` that hold the python code you want to exectute before commit. In my case this was a call to the test runner: `PATH_TO_ENV\python.exe PATH_TO_FILE/prehook_runner.py`. This will be called by the bat file so make sure this runs in the Command Prompt.
- put the code yopu want to run pre-commit in prehook_runner.py. My code ([origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41054522)):

  ```
  import sys
  import unittest

  test_suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('.\\Test', 'test*.py')
  test_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(resultclass=unittest.TextTestResult)
  result = test_runner.run(test_suite)
  if not result.wasSuccessful():
      print('')
      print('')
      print('SOME TESTS FAILED. You can still commit, but be aware.')
      print('')
      print('')
      print('')
  sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
  ```

This would generate a popup if the tests fail.