# Python Unittest Discover return exit code 0 even if fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have read several posts saying that if you call your unittests with unittest.main() that they should exit with a failure code if they fail. I call my unittests with the command: `python -m unittest discover -v`. I am using Python 3.6.6. An example unittest could look like this:

```
from server import app
import unittest

class ServerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Unittesting for the server application.
    """


    def setUp(self):
        """
        Create a test client
        """
        self.app = app.test_client()
        self.app.testing = True 

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_root_endpoint(self):
        """
        Testing the root endpoint
        """

        result = self.app.get('/') 
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 200) 

    def test_health_endpoint(self):
        """
        Testing the health endpoint
        """

        result = self.app.get('/health')
        assert b'UP' in result.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Even if one of my tests fails I get this when checking the exit code:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit test script returns exit code = 0 even if tests fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972098/unit-test-script-returns-exit-code-0-even-if-tests-fail)

Comment: @bjmc That post top answer is saying that he is not using `unittest.main` and that he therefore needs to use a workaround. I am using `unittest.main` and getting same problem anyway, so different cases

Answer (score 0):

Did you name the unittest files something like `test_*.py`? Because that's what discover is looking for. Otherwise no matter your tests, the result will be:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK
```

(BTW you don't have to `if __name__ ... unittest.main()` when using `-m unittest discover`)

Comment: The tests are running. I can get back 7/8 success, 1 failed, but still exit code 0.

Comment: Okay, that's weird. I can't reproduce that behaviour; for me the exit code is what you'ld expect (0=test successful, 1=test(s) failed). Sorry, I'm all out of ideas. Can you provide the exact command line and output?