# Stop/fail docker build if tests fail

Tags: python, unit-testing, docker

My aim is to force the docker build to fail if the Unittests have not all passed. I'm using the following line in my DockerFile:

`RUN python3 -m unittest discover test`

My unit tests are in classes in the test directory. The tests are run, but a failed test does not result in a failed build.

I know that a non-zero exit code is how to stop a build, but that does not seem to occur using this command.

Comment: Post the output of the failure. If you replace that line with "exit 1" does the build stop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972098/unit-test-script-returns-exit-code-0-even-if-tests-fail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit test script returns exit code = 0 even if tests fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972098/unit-test-script-returns-exit-code-0-even-if-tests-fail) (That's the question linked by @LiorCohen)

Comment: But these are if you are using a script - I'd rather just run a command in the DockerFile and exit if the tests are not all successful

Comment: The docker build will fail if any step does not return 0, so your problem boils down to "How do I make unittest return nonzero if there's a failure". Which is what the linked question is all about.

Comment: I'm just surprised you have to write another script to implement this, and there isn't a command that will do this.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem : Fail the docker build if unittest fails in azure pipeline 
I put the below code in my build.yml file.

`errors=$(docker logs careplan-tests-1 2>&1 | grep "FAILED" -c)
        if [ $errors > 0 ]; then
          echo -e "unittest tests failed"
          docker rm apiunittest
          exit 1
        fi`

Gives the output as "##[error]Bash exited with code '1'." in docker build and fails the azure pipeline.